# Post carousel in wordpress not working

Tags: wordpress

```
 <div class="row weOffer">
            <div class="col-12">
                <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                  <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    I want this to be come from loop 
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
                  </ol>
                  <div class="carousel-inner">
                     <!-- active class -->
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3">
                            <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                            <span class="layer">image</span>
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center position-relative">
                                <strong class="text-white">$150</strong>
                              </div>
                            <div class="card-body">                
                              <h5>heading</h5>
                              <p class="card-text">this id dummy text</p>                  
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                       there are 3 more div of same 
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- inactive class -->
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3">
                            <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                            <span class="layer">image</span>
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center position-relative">
                                <strong class="text-white">$150</strong>
                              </div>
                            <div class="card-body">                
                              <h5>heading</h5>
                              <p class="card-text">this id dummy text</p>                  
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                       there are 3 more div of same 
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <!-- inactive class -->

            </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I have added the HTML structure please check 
for both active and in active class
I want all of them work from a loop 
I have post inside carousel I want 4 posts to display on carousel after that onw indicater is added after every 4 posts one indicator from indicator

Comment: could you elaborate or explain what exactly you want with your entire code

Comment: I have post inside carousel I want 4 posts to display on carousel after that onw indicater is added after every 4 posts one indicator from indicator but this also dynamically add 1 after 4 posts
 <ol class="carousel-indicators">
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
                    <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
                  </ol>

Comment: please update your question and add entire code of your template so ican see that how your html structure is so i can help you

Comment: please check the updated question

Comment: do you need indicators after both active as well as inactive posts?

Comment: i need indicator after every 4 posts like if 8 posts then 2 indictor display if 12 then 3 indicators like that

Answer (score 0):

add below code then it might work for both `active` and `inactive` as well as for `indicators`

```
<div class="row weOffer">
    <div class="col-12">
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
            <?php $post_args = array
                        (
                            'post_type' => 'your_post_type_name',
                            'post_status' => 'publish',
                            'posts_per_page' => -1
                        );
                $post_query = new WP_Query($post_args);
                if($post_query->have_posts())
                { 
                    $count = 0;
                    while($post_query()->have_posts()) : $post_query->the_post();
                    {
              if($count%4==0){?>
            <ol class="carousel-indicators">
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
              I want this to be come from loop 
              <li data-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
            </ol>
            <div class="carousel-inner">
            <?php }?>
                    <div class="carousel-item <?php if($count < 4){?>active <?php }?>">
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12 col-lg-3">
                            <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                            <span class="layer">image</span>
                            <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center position-relative">
                                <strong class="text-white">$150</strong>
                              </div>
                            <div class="card-body">                
                              <h5>heading</h5>
                              <p class="card-text">this id dummy text</p>                  
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                       there are 3 more div of same 
                      </div>
                    </div>  
             if($count%4==0){ </div> <?php } ?>
             <?php $count++; } } wp_reset_query();?>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it display error for if($post_query()){   Function name must be a string

Comment: updated the code of answer as `if($post_query())` is wrong so replace with this `if($post_query->have_posts())`

Comment: slider is not working now all the images are displaying in vertical

Comment: could you please share link so i can understand how its displaying?